# Linking background CSS Images in a created Joomla module

Tags: php, javascript, css, joomla, module

I have recently created a Joomla module that's a slider. Only problem is that it loads images through a Background:Url CSS property and the images are in a folder in the module but it doesnt seem to want to link unless i insert the full URL in.

I noticed "baseurl ?>" is how they link the stylesheets, but that doesnt seem to want to work on a Background:Url CSS property.

Any Help please.

Thanks

Comment: Post the code that isn't working.

Comment: put how you use the url style

Comment: Hi, this one works "background: url(http://server/bamboo/modules/mod_touchheader/tmpl/images/h-slider-1.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0;"

but this doesnt "background: url(images/h-slider-1.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url to the image must be relative to the CSS file path.

If your CSS-file is at *modules/mod_touchheader/css/style.css*,
then your url to the image must be *url(../tmpl/images/h-slider-1.jpg)*.